# React Redux Private Route Best Practise

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router

What would be the best practice for private routing? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but when user logged in I already am redirect to the /login page

And my second question: Which of these versions is better or you have even better idea?

Code:

Auth

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isUserLoggedIn: null,
    isLoading: false,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(me.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
        state.isLoading = false
      })
      .addCase(me.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      })
  },
})

export const me = createAsyncThunk('auth/me', async () => {
  try {
    const user = await userService.getUserData()
    return { userData: user.data.data }
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
    return message
  }
})
```

**CASE 1:**

App

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(me())
  }, [])

  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  return (
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes isAuthenticated={auth.isUserLoggedIn} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Routes

```
export const AppRoutes = ({ isAuthenticated }) => (
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path='/login'
      element={<Login />}
    />
    <Route
      path='/dashboard'
      element={
        <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}>
          <Stats />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
    ...
```

PrivateRoute

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children, isAuthenticated }) => {
  return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to='/login' />
}
```

**CASE 2:**

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Routes

```
export const AppRoutes =  () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route
      path='/login'
      element={<Login />}
    />
    <Route
      path='/dashboard'
      element={
        <PrivateRoute>
          <Stats />
        </PrivateRoute>
      }
    />
  ...
```

PrivateRoute

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserLoggedIn === null) {
      dispatch(me())
    }
  }, [])

  return isUserLoggedIn ? children : <Navigate to='/login' />
}
```

CASE 1 or CASE 2 is better to approach or maybe you have a better idea?

For these 2 ideas, it redirects very quickly to /login when I go to /dashboard

What I want to achieve is good practice, quick verification, and waiting until we receive a positive response from the backend that the user is authenticated

Team, what do you suggest?

**EDIT**

New version:

**Redux**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isUserLoggedIn: null,
    isLoading: true,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(me.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
        state.isLoading = false
      })
      .addCase(me.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      })
  },
})

export const me = createAsyncThunk('auth/me', async ({}, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    const user = await userService.getUserData()
    return { userData: user.data.data }
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
    thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    return message
  }
})
```

**PrivateRoute**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isLoading, isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  if (isLoading) return null 

  return isUserLoggedIn ? (
    children
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to='/login'
      replace
    />
  )
}
```

**App**

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserLoggedIn === null) {
      dispatch(me())
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Store**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),
})
```

**Index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

But when I reload the page I go to `/login` don't stay at the same page like `/dashboard` how could I cope with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem! Ha ha!

Seems stupid && simple but it started working ->

**Redux**

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isUserLoggedIn: null,
    isLoading: true,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(me.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
        state.isLoading = false
      })
      .addCase(me.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      })
  },
})

export const me = createAsyncThunk('auth/me', async (_, thunkAPI) => { // <- {} replaced to _ and this is it! 
  try {
    const user = await userService.getUserData()
    return { userData: user.data.data }
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString()
    thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message)
    return message
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Either approach is fine. The issue you are seeing is based on the initial redux state value being used for auth check and redirection ***prior*** to the effect running to set the auth state. You will want to hold off on redirecting until the authentication status is determined. Use the state to rendering null or some loading indicator until a user is verified authenticated.

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    isUserLoggedIn: null,
    isLoading: true, // <-- assume initially loading state from mouting
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(me.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload.userData
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
        state.isLoading = false
      })
      .addCase(me.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      })
  },
});
```

Between the two implementations IMO the second is preferred as it leads to less component coupling. I suggest a mix of the two. Check for a user in `App` and dispatch the action to set the auth state, and check the auth state in the private route.

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isUserLoggedIn === null) {
      dispatch(me());
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div data-theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRoutes />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { isLoading, isUserLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth)

  if (isLoading) return null; // <-- or loading spinner, etc...

  return isUserLoggedIn ? children : <Navigate to='/login' replace />
}
```

The same can be achieved with the first version, you'd just need to pass the `isLoading` state along with the `isUserLoggedIn` state as props to the `PrivateRoute`.

Comment: Great Idea! I did it as you mention, but there left only one problem -> when I reload the page then it goes to /login (because it needs some time to verify). Any ideas?

Comment: After reloading the page I get to /login, maybe we should use some history and come back to the previous route?

What about performance? Is it a good idea, what would be the best approach? :)